# Change some of numpy array columns according to logical condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `2D` `NumPy` array, and I want to perform the following operation:

For each column in the array, which is a series of non-decreasing values, replace this column with a column of the differences (that is, each entry is the difference between the two previous ones).

Every other column remains the same (except that first row is removed to fit to the differences columns dimension).

For example, in the matrix:

```
[ [1,1,1,2,3,4]
  [1,3,4,3,4,5]
  [1,7,3,4,2,7] ]
```

The differences matrix is:

```
[ [0,2,3,1,1,1]
  [0,4,-1,1,-1,2] ]
```

And thus the third and fifth columns which have decreasing values will remain the same, while other columns are replaced with the differences columns, resulting with:

```
[ [0,2,4,1,4,1]
  [0,4,3,1,2,2] ]
```

I tried something like this:

```
tempX = np.diff(X, axis = 0).transpose()
return np.where(tempX >= 0, tempX, X[1:].transpose())
```

But the condition in `np.where` is performed element-wise and not for each column (or row).

How can I change the condition so it will work? Is there a more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: Could you use a bigger array as sample and more variety in numbers?

Comment: It's hard to understand if there is a typo in your example. ;) I guess, it should be "will be changed to `[ [0, 2, 1] [0, 4, 3] ]`", right?

Comment: I changed the example, I hope it is clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
# Get the differentiation along first axis
diffs = np.diff(a,axis=0)

# Mask of invalid ones
mask = (diffs<0).any(0)

# Use the mask to set the invalid ones to the original elements
diffs[:,mask] = a[1:,mask]
```

Sample run -

```
In [141]: a
Out[141]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 7, 3, 4, 2, 7]])

In [142]: diffs = np.diff(a,axis=0)
     ...: mask = (diffs<0).any(0)
     ...: diffs[:,mask] = a[1:,mask]
     ...: 

In [143]: diffs
Out[143]: 
array([[0, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1],
       [0, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it so:

```
b = a[1:] - a[:-1]
decrease = numpy.where(numpy.min(b, axis=0)<0)
b[:,decrease] = a[1:, decrease]
```

You can also do that in one expression:

```
numpy.where(numpy.min(a[1:]-a[:-1],axis=0)>=0, a[1:]-a[:-1], a[1:])
```